# TimeoutException unhandled by the code, do I need a try catch when using Polly?

Tags: c#, exception, polly

I've been working with a remote web service over an unreliably and/or slow VPN that brought to light a point of failure in my code when I call a web service I will get timeout exceptions.

I did a little googling and found Polly and seemed to be exactly what I needed, but I'm still getting an unhandled `TimeoutException` and would like to know what I'm doing wrong and how to update the code so that the `TimeoutException` is handled, preferably using Polly.

```
        var networkPolicy = Policy
              .Handle<TimeoutException>()
              .Or<CommunicationException>()
              .WaitAndRetry(
                   5,
                   retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
                   (exception, timeSpan, context) =>
                   {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception being retried" + exception );
                   });
        // The following line is giving me the exception.
        response = networkPolicy.Execute(() => soapClient.WebServiceFunction(request));
```

I'd also like to know if it is best practice to define the policy as a static readonly variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polly works so that repeated operations if an error occurs, but only a certain number of times. If the error occurs more times Polly throws it.

If you want to repeat it until when it is not thrown expetion then use `RetryForever`.

Usually I use Polly with a try catch - like here:

```
    try
    {
        return
            await
            Policy.Handle<MongoConnectionException>()
                  .RetryAsync(3,
                      (exception, i) =>
                          {
                              logger.Warn(exception,
                                  string.Format("Mongo Connection Exception - Retry Count : {0}", i));
                          })
                  .ExecuteAsync(async () => await operation());
    }
    catch (MongoConnectionException ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This is a great pattern.  Since this answer, Polly has also added `.ExecuteAndCapture()` and `.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync()`, which captures the final exception for you, so you don't have to write an additional `try / catch { }`.  More details [in the Polly readme](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#post-execution-capturing-the-result-or-any-final-exception)